# How do I call setState from a child Component to another child component in ReactJs

Tags: react-hooks, react-props

function Booking() {
const [count, setCount] = useState(1);

return (
<>

#### ₦{3 * count}

</>

};
i want the count to appear inside another component, maintaining its state from the current component.

Comment: Do they have same parent ?

Comment: yes, they share same parent

Comment: I would have used useContext if its from a parent to the child.